# Reinstalling Default Website for Exchange 2010

Tags: windows, exchange

The Default Website for Exchange 2010 on Windows SBS Server 2010 has been deleted (how and why is not important).

Now, obviously, I cant access emails via OWA or via HTTP for people offsite.

I can not figure out how to reinstall the default website to reinstall OWA and settings? I also can't log into Exchange Mangement Console. The attempt to connect to... using "kerberos" jauthenication failed (probably because it does not exist).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has [an article summarizing the PowerShell cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629372.aspx) that can be used to recreate the client access virtual directories with links to the specific usage for each cmdlet. There's also a GUI option that they describe but since you're having trouble opening the Exchange Management Console that option probably won't work for you.

Basically, you're running a suite of cmdlets to remove the old virtual directories (which you indicate are gone already but, just for safety's sake, it's a good idea to run the remove cmdlets) and then running a series of cmdlets to re-create them.

Assuming your server is "SBSSERVER", the cmdlets to remove the virtual directories are:

```
Remove-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\Autodiscover (Default Web Site)'
Remove-EcpVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\ecp (Default Web Site)'
Remove-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\EWS (Default Web Site)'
Remove-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync (Default Web Site)'
Remove-OABVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\OAB (Default Web Site)'
Remove-OwaVirtualDirectory -Identity 'SBSSERVER\owa (default Web Site)'
```

To re-create the virtual directories:

```
New-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -name 'Autodiscover' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
New-EcpVirtualDirectory -name 'ecp' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
New-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -name 'EWS' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -name 'Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
New-OABVirtualDirectory -name 'OAB' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
New-OwaVirtualDirectory -name 'owa' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
```

If you need to set special external or internal URLs for the sites (your public-facing FQDN on the OWA site, for example) you can add the appropriate `ExternalURL` or `InternalURL` argument to these cmdlets to set the URL at the time of creation.

Answer (score 0):

http://exchangeadventures.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/recreate-exchange-iis-virtual-directories-with-exchange-2010-sp1/

That should be what you need.